# how to change color of a column in datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, formatting

I have a DataGridview, and I'm setting some of the columns to readonly for data entry purposes.  When I do that, the column stays the normal white (although it does not allow entry).  How can I color the column gray?  I've seen lots of samples on how to color rows, but not columns.

How can I make the readonly columns look gray?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try setting the ***DefaultCellStyle*** property for the selected columns.

**Edit:**

```
grid.Columns["NameOfColumn"].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
```

Comment: ForeColor changes the text color. BackColor changes the background color.

Answer (score 14):

just change the style for the DataGridViewColumn object,

```
myGrid.Columns["myColumn"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: -Gave you +1 for the right way to change it (and especially for using the columnname instead of the index, I hate using the index), but I wanted gray.... not red.  :-)

Comment: its Color.Red not Colors.Red

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the cell background colours for a column like so using the [DefaultCellStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.defaultcellstyle.aspx) property of a DataGridViewColumn.

```
DataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        DataGridViewColumn firstColumn = dataGridView.Columns[0];
        DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        cellStyle.BackColor = Color.Grey;

        firstColumn.DefaultCellStyle = cellStyle;
```

Comment: -I see this would work, but way more code than the other solutions.