# Disable event handler from a method

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, telerik-grid

In my datagridview, I have got some columns are `read only`, so i have given in some color. 
When I load the the DGV in advance view with all columns including read only. 
When the user cliks on Normal View I want to just display the normal eitable cols and hide the read only columns and the color.

I'm on telerik and using radgrid.

I tried the below approach but it's not working. Is there any better way of doing this?? Thank you.

```
private void normalToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Normal View
{
    DTURradGridView.Columns[2].IsVisible = false;
    DTURradGridView.Columns[3].IsVisible = false;
    DTURradGridView.Columns[4].IsVisible = false;
    DTURradGridView.Columns[5].IsVisible = false;
    DTURradGridView.Columns[7].IsVisible = false;
    DTURradGridView.Columns[11].IsVisible = false;

    DTURradGridView.Columns[2].ReadOnly = false;
    DTURradGridView.Columns[3].ReadOnly = false;
    DTURradGridView.Columns[4].ReadOnly = false;
    DTURradGridView.Columns[5].ReadOnly = false;
    DTURradGridView.Columns[7].ReadOnly = false;
    DTURradGridView.Columns[11].ReadOnly = false;

    DTURradGridView.CellFormatting -= DTURradGridView_CellFormatting;
}

private void advancedToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Advanced View
{
    DTURradGridView.Columns[2].IsVisible = true;
    DTURradGridView.Columns[3].IsVisible = true;
    DTURradGridView.Columns[4].IsVisible = true;
    DTURradGridView.Columns[5].IsVisible = true;
    DTURradGridView.Columns[7].IsVisible = true;
    DTURradGridView.Columns[11].IsVisible = true;

    DTURradGridView.Columns[2].ReadOnly = true;
    DTURradGridView.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true;
    DTURradGridView.Columns[4].ReadOnly = true;
    DTURradGridView.Columns[5].ReadOnly = true;
    DTURradGridView.Columns[7].ReadOnly = true;
    DTURradGridView.Columns[11].ReadOnly = true;

    DTURradGridView.CellFormatting += DTURradGridView_CellFormatting;   
}

private void DTURradGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, CellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CellElement.ColumnIndex != 2 && e.CellElement.ColumnIndex != 3 && e.CellElement.ColumnIndex != 4
    && e.CellElement.ColumnIndex != 5 && e.CellElement.ColumnIndex != 7 && e.CellElement.ColumnIndex != 11) return;

    e.CellElement.DrawFill = true;
    e.CellElement.NumberOfColors = 1;
    e.CellElement.BackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
    e.CellElement.GradientStyle = GradientStyles.Linear;    
}
```

When I click on the normal view, I see the colors of the col index 2,3,4,5. So the -= is not working.

Comment: What is the result that you are getting?

Comment: In the noraml mode, i see the color for the cols which are not read only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better approach would be to set read-only columns and their color once at form startup, preferably by name. See [How to change color of a column in datagridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491700/how-to-change-color-of-a-column-in-datagridview)

Then iterate through columns and hide or show those which are readonly, depending on which mode you are in. Having it hard-coded like this is not a good practice:

```
DTURradGridView.Columns[2].ReadOnly = true;
DTURradGridView.Columns[3].ReadOnly = true;
DTURradGridView.Columns[4].ReadOnly = true;
```

Who knows what's 2, 3, 4? Nobody. Problem is you can easily get lost in your own code.

Comment: I can do the readonly programatically at startup but how about cell formatting??

Comment: @linguini: Same thing, set it once at form startup. Then you don't need to change it, because once hidden, you don't care about their color.

Comment: @ Neolisk: If the user wants to see the contents that they have to differentiate among all the cols thats why i need color

Comment: @linguini: I'm not saying remove color, I'm saying colorize once and don't change it every time. Is it possible to do?

Comment: @linguini: well, try to rewrite your code then, to account for the above guidelines and let us know how it goes.

Comment: @linguini: I updated my answer - see how you can stop using `DTURradGridView_CellFormatting` and switch to `DefaultCellStyle` instead, which can be done once at form startup.

Comment: I have changed everything at runtime for readonly and in the telerik radgrid i have assigned the color by cellFormatting beacuse there is no defaultcellstyle option. Then i tried to run it,when i click on noraml mode i see colors for the other cols.

Comment: @linguini: You should have said that your are not using native DataGridView control, because it is a game changer, and not clear from your question. Well in this case modify your code, so you don't work by column index and let us know what you get. Should be much easier to troubleshoot when you're done.

Comment: I changed, everything by col name including for the color and when i click on normal mode the color applied to other cols.