# How to color all cells in a column in a datagridview on a form in C#?

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

I had custom column colors set using

```
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
dataGridView1.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
dataGridView1.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
```

but I accidentally changed the default row template color in the designer window and now my colors only applies to the top row and not the entire column.

I can't find a way to override the default row template to set custom colors for whole column.

[BEFORE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxmWr.png)

[NOW/AFTER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfaBz.png)

I have tried using `CellFormatting` but this did not resolve my issue

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491700/how-to-change-color-of-a-column-in-datagridview

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/cell-styles-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#style-inheritance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change color of a column in datagridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491700/how-to-change-color-of-a-column-in-datagridview)